# Add two different suffixes to wordpress custom post type permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I've created a CPT called "city" using following code:

```
function custom_post_type() {
 
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'city'),
    'description'         => __( 'City news and reviews'),
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array('post_tag'),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-admin-multisite',

);
 
// Registering your Custom Post Type
register_post_type( 'city', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

I've created a new city with "Paris" name, where I have a lot of custom fields.

The permalink to access the CPT page now is:

**[www.example.com/city/paris](http://www.example.com/city/paris)**

I need to edit the CPT permalink into two different permalinks:

**[www.example.com/city/paris-travel-guide](http://www.example.com/city/paris-travel-guide)**

**[www.example.com/city/paris-price-guide](http://www.example.com/city/paris-price-guide)**

I need that in order to display some custom fields on the first link and another part of custom fields on the second link.

Does  anybody has any ideas how to implement that on wordpress?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why you need three permalinks for a single post.

Comment: I need just last two of them

Comment: And do the permalinks point to separate pages?

Comment: Yes, two different templates.